# How can I click on an icon using capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, cucumber, capybara

[I want to test the Heart icon- The method should click on the Heart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmRnY.png) I am using capybara to test the favorite feature ("Heart icon"). I am new to capybara-cucumber. So would like to know if there is any method to click on the heart icon in capybara.

I am using this code.

```
Then (/^I should see heart icon on every product$/) do
      Capybara.page.find('i.heart.icon-heart-outline').click
end
```

But it is throwing out an error.

```
Unable to find css "i.heart.icon-heart-outline" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

Sample of HTML code is as below.

```
<favorite class="product-action ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" ng-if="!ui.showIpsaProductCell()" product="result"><a class="ng-scope not-active" ng-click="toggle(true)" active="::product.favoriting" ng-mouseenter="product.showList = true" ng-mousedown="product.favoriting = true">
  <i class="heart icon-heart-outline" ng-class="::{
    'icon-heart-filled':
      product.hasFavorite || !showCount || newProductPage,
    'icon-heart-outline':
      !product.hasFavorite &amp;&amp; showCount &amp;&amp; !newProductPage
  }"></i>
  <!-- ngIf: ::showCount --><span ng-if="::showCount" class="count ng-scope">
    1
  </span><!-- end ngIf: ::showCount -->
  <!-- ngIf: ::addToList && product.hasFavorite -->
</a>
</favorite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely getting ElementNotFound because the element is not considered visible on the page.  This could be because the css you're using to display the icon is ending up with the size of the `<i>` element being 0px by 0px -- If you can adjust the css to give it some size it should work, or try clicking on the `<a>` element that wraps the i - something like

```
find(:xpath, ".//a[i[contains(@class, 'icon-heart-outline')]]").click
```

If you're getting ambiguous matches then you'll need to scope the find to the correct element on the page - looking at the image you linked to, if each block is a div with class item then you could do something like

```
find('div.item', text: 'Baseball Cap').find(:xpath, ".//a[i[contains(@class, 'icon-heart-outline')]]").click
```

This would scope the second find to only look for the heart inside the block that has the baseball cap description in it

Comment: @ChintanVadgama  - I added an update for ambiguous matches that you commented on in the other answer

Answer (score 0):

```
find('only one class here').click

Capybara.page.find('.icon-heart-outline').click
```

Comment: There is no requirement in capybara to only have one class -- it can take any valid css (or xpath if specified) selector

Comment: Hey Tom that error got resolved. But as there are multiple elements having the same xpath it's giving 

`Ambiguous match, found 33 elements matching xpath ".//a[child::i[contains(@class,\"icon-heart-outline\")]]" (Capybara::Ambiguous)` ERROR